# struct program in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

In the below program,i am not getting values from `printf`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
    float price;
    int pages;
    };
    struct book b1,b2,b3;

    printf("enter names prices & no. of pages of 3 books\n");
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.pages);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.pages);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("and this is what you entered\n");
    printf("%c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);
    printf("%c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.pages);
    printf("%c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.pages);
    return 0;
}
```

and this output I am getting

```
enter names prices & no. of pages of 3 books
a 34.6 23
b 23.4 34
c 63.5 23

and this is what you entered

0.000000 0∞ 0.000000 0╪ 0.000000 0Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why isn't the output matching the input?

Comment: Most `printf()` formats need a newline at the end, unless you're consciously building up a single line of output out of multiple calls to `printf()`.  What's more, you may not see the output if you do not include a newline or use `fflush(stdout)` or `fflush(0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);
printf("%c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.pages);
printf("%c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.pages);
```

Too much copy and paste methinks. You are passing pointers when `printf` expects `char`s, same for the floats and ints.

You passed the address of those variables to `scanf` so that the function could change their value.  When you use `%d`, `%f`, and `%c` `printf` expects an int (not a pointer to int), a float (not a pointer to float), and a char (not a pointer to char).

Comment: thnx,i deleted   & in    printf statement,now its working properly.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your program:

- `char` fits a single character. It is not big enough to store book's title.
- You pass addresses to `scanf`, but you pass values to `printf` (i.e. no `&` on `printf`'s parameters, except possibly to `%p`'s parameters)
- You do not need to `fflush` your input streams - it has no effect.

I think you should change `char name` to `char name[101]` (or whatever other max size you'd prefer), and `scanf("%c...", &b1.name,...)` for `scanf("%100s...", b1.name,...)`. Note how the ampersand `&` is missing from `b1.name`: this is because arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK, I deleted the comment :)